# ClojureScript Electron app __dirname returns nil

Tags: node.js, clojure, electron, clojurescript

I'm writing Electron app with ClojureScript and getting this weird behavior:

```
(ns hello-world.core
  (:require [cljs.nodejs :as nodejs]))

(nodejs/enable-util-print!)

(def electron (nodejs/require "electron"))

(def app (.-app electron))

(defn on-ready []
  (prn (js* "__dirname"))) ; => nil

(defn -main [& args]
      (prn (js* "__dirname")) ; => "/Users/alex/source/electron-cljs/out"
      (.on app "ready" on-ready))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

As you can see, __dirname is resolved fine in -main function, but it returns nil in my electron "ready" callback. Why is it not working inside the callback?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will fix it for you, but you could try using `js/__dirname` instead of `js*`? `js*` is an internal function used by ClojureScript, and not for public use AFAIK.